# UIWebview with SwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have an `UIWebview`, when user taps a `UIButton`, my webview will be loaded. I have an 10 HTML files in `bundle` i want to show the first html in webview and when user `**swipes**` i want to show the next HTML file. When user wants to see previous HTML file, i want to allow swipe and see. I have used `UISwipeGesture` but how can i load the files one by one.. Please help me. I have loaded the files from bundle and i used

```
NSURLREQUEST *req = [NSURLREQUEST  requestwithURL : myURL];
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

myURL is the path for first HTML. How can i do this for 10 HTML files using **SWIPE**

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing you can do is rename your HTML files like 1.html, 2.html ..... 10.html
Declare an integar variable in your .h file initialize it in viewDidLoad and on detecting swipe right increment in that variable and use formatString to make correct url and reload the webview and on detecting swipe left decrement in that variable make correct url and reload the webview.

```
-(void)swipeRightDetected
{
    if(fileNumber <= 10)
    {
        fileNumber++;
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://172.161.331.25/casa/admmathematic/Page00%d.html",fileNumber];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [webview loadRequest:request];
    }
    else
   {
        //No more files
   }
}

-(void)swipeLeftDetected
{
    if(fileNumber > 0)
    {
        fileNumber--;
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://172.161.331.25/casa/admmathematic/Page00%d.html",fileNumber];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
        NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
        [webview loadRequest:request];
    }
    else
    {
        //No more files
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting URL's like this   "http://172.161.331.25/casa/admmathematic/Page001.html",
    "http://172.161.331.25/casa/admmathematic/Page002.html",
    "http://172.161.331.25/casa/admmathematic/Page003.html",